# Callbacks between azure service fabric services?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm calling a Actor which calls a stateless service.

Now I need stateless service to send an acknowledgement back to Actor (callback), once it completes its work.

Is there any mechnism to achieve this in service fabric ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass [ActorReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorreference.get.aspx) to the stateless service and then [bind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorreference.bind.aspx) the ActorReference to the actor interface type on the receiving side. You can cast the return value of bind method to the actor interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common approach to such kind of communication is to use Service Bus Queues and Pub/Sub pattern
https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus

When u need to send the acknowledgement u just publish this message to the MessageBus and handle it in the Actor(subscriber)